# Is it good practice to create subfolders off the %TEMP% folder?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, temporary-files

If I look at my `%TEMP%` folder (that is, `C:\Documents and Settings\Me\Local Settings\Temp\`), I see some applications stick stuff in there, and some applications stick it into a subfolder off there. Sometimes those subfolders have names that can be traced back to the application or the author, and some are random.

- Is there any best practice here?
- Does it matter?
- Does the whole folder get deleted if you do a disk cleanup?
- What about `C:\Windows\Temp`? When is that used by applications other than Windows itself - if ever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no best practice I'm familiar with. It is a directory for temporary files, and it is most likely going to look like a garbage can. As a developer, I find it easier for me to create a directory with my application's name and place all my files there, and even clean it if I can. But I think that is just a good habit - nothing that the OS will be upset about.
2. It matters only to those that need these files. If you generate a lot of files and used them later - you need to keep track of them. It is easier when they are all in the same directory. Also, every operating system has a limitation to how many files a directory can hold, so it is never good practice to put many files in the same directory.
3. [Disk Cleanup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Cleanup) allows you to delete it - it is not done automatically unless you configure it somehow.
4. I personally favor `C:\WINDOWS\Temp` - so I change my `%TEMP%` to point to it. It is usually internal for Windows components, but Windows works fine if my junk goes there as well. I recall someone once told me that everything under `C:\Documents and Settings\myuser` is a part of the user profile - so the less files there the faster your computer is. I don't know if it is true, but I avoid putting temporary files there anyway.

Comment: ...Cosmin was a close second

Answer (score 1):

C:\windows\temp is used by processes running as Local System, Local Service, and Network Service.